# Android private signed key

Tags: android

when i am creating my own private key for my application. keystore file is created successfully. but when i'm creating MD5 certification the following error is occurred.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keys
tore "C:\MD5\vijay1.keystore"
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias  does not exist

Answer (score 2):

keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore /PATH_TO/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android